# How can Editor Templates / Display Templates recognize any Attributes assigned to them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add a `[Required]` attribute to my `DateTime` editor template so that I can add the appropriate validation schemes or a `DataType.Date` attribute so I know when I should only display dates. But I can't figure out how to get the metadata that says which attributes the Editor Template has assigned to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The built-in attributes, such as `[Required]` assign different properties on the metadata (see the blog post I have linked at the end of my answer to learn more). For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

would assign:

```
@{
    var isRequired = ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired;
}
```

in the corresponding editor/display template.

And if you had a custom attribute:

```
public class MyCustomStuffAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["customStuff"] = "some very custom stuff";
    }
}
```

and a view model decorated with it:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [MyCustomStuff]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

in the corresponding editor/display template you could fetch this:

```
@{
    var myCustomStuff = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["customStuff"];
}
```

Also you should absolutely read Brad Wilson's [series of blog posts](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) about what ModelMetadata and templates in ASP.NET MVC is and how to use it.