# Specify custom formatting in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

[Django has the concept of filters that allow you to format values in views.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/)

E.g. if you have a file size in bytes of 123456789 then you can use in your view

```
{{ value|filesizeformat }}
```

to display 117.7 MB.

(This is one example - there are many others such a pluralize, humanize, timesince, timeuntil etc).

Whats the best way of doing this in ASP.NET MVC3 where the **view will determine the format to be used** (e.g. some views will show files size in bytes, other views in more human readable format).

To spell it out - I am aware that you can do this in custom templates, but can't figure out how you could have different templates for the same value and specify in the view which one to use.

Comment: Have a look at Display/Editor Templates. That should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I somehow missed that you could name the template to use and provide additionalViewData - think thats new in MVC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your `DisplayTemplate` for example `Pinguin.cshtml`, you can make a call to `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyProperty, "Pinguin")` and it will utilize your template (using the parameter `additionalViewdata`).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Display/Editor Templates. That should be what you are looking for.
Some good posts on this matter:

1) [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 1: Introduction](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)

2) [asp.net MVC DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplate naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2317039/1437962)

3) [How can Editor Templates / Display Templates recognize any Attributes assigned to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7313284/1437962)